# Cannot use UITableView registerClass(_, forCellReuseIdentifier: ) to deregister a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I can register a UITableViewCell with

```
table.registerClass(SignEntryCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SignEntry")
```

The documentation says I should be able to deregister

> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces the old entry. You may specify nil for cellClass if you want to unregister the class from the specified reuse identifier.

But using

```
table.registerClass(nil, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SignEntry")
```

gives me the following compiler error message

> Cannot invoke 'registerClass' with an argument list of type '(nil, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)'

Does anyone know how to deregister a cell from a table?

Comment: Why do you need unregister it?

Comment: give your full code of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Trying to write a lengthy justification of why I needed 96 lines of code and comments, made me realise I did not need it.

Answer (score 2):

The approach(unregister) is unavailable in Swift. You will get a error if you passing a non-UITableViewCell:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'must pass a class of kind UITableViewCell'
***
```

The cellClass is not an optional type so you can't pass a nil. In fact, we use almost nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is helpful for you.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    var cell:SignEntryCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? SignEntryCell
    if  (cell==nil)
    {
        var nib:NSArray=NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SignEntryCell", owner: self, options: nil)
        cell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? SignEntryCell
    }
    return true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell().classForCoder, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```